# Reading files from FTP using Pentaho Kettle

Tags: ftp, sftp, pentaho

Can someone please throw some light on this? I have an FTP server to which some external vendors will copy the data to. I need to create a Pentaho kettle job that copies the data from the FTP server to the NAS. I don't have any control on the data being written to the FTP and the vendors have told that they will not create the .done file to intimate us that the file write is complete. How can I create a job that check and copies only the files which are completely written to the FTP,

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 job with following steps,

start -> get files from FTPS -> Sucess

Give your ftp details under General , Under files give remote directory location, give target directory location.

In advance tab, specify file size according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you.My real concern is to copy only the files which are copy complete d and not the files which are still being copied to the FTP. Please read my question again.

Comment: you have to fix a time for it, because files will not going to copy in ftp server 24 * 7, so just set your batch process time accordingly.'

Comment: unfortunately, I absolutely don't have any control on the data being ingested into the FTP. My job has to continuously check/monitor  and fetch the files which are copied completely.